# Laravel broadcast with 2 servers

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, pusher

I have an app that is build with Laravel and Vuejs on two separated servers.

Now i would like to use Laravel broadcasting with Pusher but i don't know if that will work with two servers. I know how to use broadcasting with Laravel and Vue on the same server. but how does that work if Laravel and Vue is separated?

Thank you!

Comment: Considering that Vue is client-side, where the server is shouldn't really matter

Answer (score -1):

If you want to broadcast messages *from* multiple servers to your clients, that should be absolutely fine.

If you're talking about sending messages from one server to another server, that's less straightforward.

Comment: Not an answer. Should be a comment.